# Combine Spring Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-tags

When searching Documentation for `Spring`, thirteen separate tags come up, four of which are proposals. There is no federated way to search among all those topics contained under these tags for how to do something (for instance, an example that shows combining multiple method types into a response handler). Nor is it obvious which of these a given topic would fall under (unless perhaps if you're already intimately familiar with the topic).

The immediate question is: does it make sense to merge these Documentation tags? Even though all these have their own question tags? (Are documentation tags to question tags always one to one, or n to one?) One particular argument for combining these is that almost all of these have only a handful of topics and examples under them, and they're all pretty clearly inter-related. An argument against is that, say, `spring-security` has only the Spring core in common with `spring-webflow`.

The more abstract question is does it make sense to have a federated search across some subset or filter condition of tags? I'd like to turn up example topics having to do with x question if they exist in any of those tags.

Comment: You still need to remove [documentation-topics].

Comment: @StephenLeppik Based on the description of each of those meta tags, I chose what seemed like the most appropriate one. However, there is nothing wrong with having multiple, and you're free to edit questions to add or remove tags as appropriate. I've modified it for now, though.

Comment: @StephenLeppik "For discussion and questions relating to Topics (high level categories) in the Documentation public Beta." This is directly tied to the high level categories: I'm finding 13 for Spring, and this is where the federated search problem lies. It's only tangential that they arise from the fact tags exist.

Comment: No, [documentation-topics] is about the things called "topics"—you know, the things that have examples in them. If you'll excuse me, I'm going to go edit that wiki excerpt to clarify it.

Comment: Also, I can't edit the question because I don't have 2K and this is Meta.

Comment: Why not just use an external search engine? I believe the intent here is that people get to Documentation examples via search, not by navigating from tag -> topic -> example.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me (at a glance) like all of those tags are about separate *libraries* for Spring. Sort of like how we have separate documentation for [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) (the most-used JS library), I think that these tags should remain separate documentation. If there is a separate tag that refers to something *in the Spring core*, then it should be merged, but none of them appear to meet that criteria.